# How to describe conditional statement (if-then-else) using PEG

Tags: parsing, grammar, bnf, peg, pegjs

i'm working on Qt's qmake project file parser (open source project).
And i have a trouble with describing qmake's variant of conditional statement, called "scope" in documentation.

EBNF (simplified):

```
ScopeStatement -> Condition ScopeBody

Condition -> Identifier | TestFunctionCall | NotExpr | OrExpr | AndExpr
NotExpr -> "!" Condition
OrExpr   -> Condition "|" Condition
AndExpr -> Condition ":" Condition

ScopeBody -> COLON Statement | BR_OPEN Statement:*  BR_CLOSE

Statement -> AssignmentStatement
AssignmentStatement -> Identifier EQ String

// There are many others built-in boolean functions
TestFunctionCall -> ("defined" | ...)  ARG_LIST_OPEN (String COMMA:?):* ARG_LIST_CLOSE

Identifier -> Letter (Letter | Digit | UNDERSCP):+ String -> (Letter | Digit | UNDERSCP):+

EQ -> "="
COLON -> ":"
COMMA -> ","
ARG_LIST_OPEN -> "("
ARG_LIST_CLOSE -> ")"
BLOCK_OPEN -> "{"
BLOCK_CLOSE -> "}"
UNDERSCP -> "_"
```

First question: how to distinguish AND-operator colon from the condition terminal one? is it possible?

P.S. My grammar draft (without function call support) don't work even for simple case like

```
win32:xml: x = y
```

`PEG.JS` Code:

```
Start
  = ScopeStatement

// qmake scope statement
ScopeStatement
  = BooleanExpression ws* ((":" ws* SingleLineStatement) / ("{" ws* MultiLineStatement ))

SingleLineStatement
  = Identifier ws* "=" ws* Identifier lb* 

MultiLineStatement
  = (SingleLineStatement lb*)+

// qmake condition statement
BooleanExpression
  = BooleanOrExpression

BooleanOrExpression
  = left:BooleanAndExpression ws* "|" ws* right:BooleanOrExpression  { return {type: "OR", left:left, right:right} }
  / BooleanAndExpression

BooleanAndExpression
  = left:BooleanNotExpression ws* ":" ws* right:BooleanAndExpression  { return {type: "AND", left:left, right:right} }
  / BooleanNotExpression


BooleanNotExpression
  = "!" ws* operand:BooleanNotExpression { return {type: "NOT", operand: operand } }
  / BooleanComplexExpression


BooleanComplexExpression
  = Identifier
  / "(" logical_or:BooleanOrExpression ")" { return logical_or; }

Identifier
  = token:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ { return token.join(""); }

ws 
  = [ \t]

lb
  = [\r\n]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is a condition always terminated by another colon?

Comment: Yes, AND-condition have format bool_expr1:bool_expr2:...:bool_exprN: <statement>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a negative lookahead after the `BooleanAndExpression` for anything that is *not* a `BooleanAndExpression`, otherwise it will keep greedily consuming additional "and" expressions.

```
Start
  = ScopeStatement

// qmake scope statement
ScopeStatement
  = bool:BooleanExpression ws* state:Statement  { return {bool:bool, state:state} }

Statement
  = ":" ws* state:SingleLineStatement  { return state }

SingleLineStatement
  = left:Identifier ws* "=" ws* right:Identifier lb*  { return {type: "ASSIGN", left:left, right:right} }

MultiLineStatement
  = (SingleLineStatement lb*)+

// qmake condition statement
BooleanExpression
  = BooleanOrExpression

BooleanOrExpression
  = left:BooleanAndExpression ws* "|" ws* right:BooleanOrExpression  { return {type: "OR", left:left, right:right} }
  / BooleanAndExpression

BooleanAndExpression
  = left:BooleanNotExpression ws* !(":" ws* SingleLineStatement) ":" ws* right:BooleanAndExpression  { return {type: "AND", left:left, right:right} }
  / BooleanNotExpression


BooleanNotExpression
  = "!" ws* operand:BooleanNotExpression { return {type: "NOT", operand: operand } }
  / BooleanComplexExpression


BooleanComplexExpression
  = Identifier
  / "(" logical_or:BooleanOrExpression ")" { return logical_or; }

Identifier
  = token:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ { return token.join(""); }

ws 
  = [ \t]

lb
  = [\r\n]
```

Comment: Thank you, this really work! I just missed with the place for !SingleLineStatement